textList of NSParagraphStyle not working for custom UITextVIew
I tried with textList of NSParagrphStyle, it works well
    let textView = UITextView()
    textView.backgroundColor = UIColor.gray
    textView.isEditable = false
    //Create NSTextList
    let list = NSTextList(markerFormat: .decimal, options: 0)
    list.startingItemNumber = 1
    
    //Create NSParagraphStyle with text list
    let paragraphStyle = NSMutableParagraphStyle()
    paragraphStyle.textLists = [list]
    
    let attributes = [NSAttributedString.Key.paragraphStyle : paragraphStyle]
    
    //Add attributes to list block
    let nsmutableAttributedString = NSMutableAttributedString(string: "Test1\nTest2\nTest3", attributes: attributes)
    textView.attributedText = nsmutableAttributedString
    


while if I try to use custom layoutManager, then the textList is no longer working,
func getTextView() -> UITextView {
    
    let textView = CustomTextView()
    textView.backgroundColor = UIColor.gray
    textView.isEditable = false
    //Create NSTextList
    let list = NSTextList(markerFormat: .decimal, options: 0)
    list.startingItemNumber = 1
    
    //Create NSParagraphStyle with text list
    let paragraphStyle = NSMutableParagraphStyle()
    paragraphStyle.textLists = [list]
    
    let attributes = [NSAttributedString.Key.paragraphStyle : paragraphStyle]
    
    //Add attributes to list block
    let nsmutableAttributedString = NSMutableAttributedString(string: "Test1\nTest2\nTest3", attributes: attributes)
    textView.textStorage.setAttributedString(nsmutableAttributedString)
    
    return textView
}

final class CustomTextView: UITextView {

    // MARK: - Initializer

    public override init(frame: CGRect, textContainer: NSTextContainer?) {
        let layoutManager = NSLayoutManager()
        let textStorage = NSTextStorage()
        textStorage.addLayoutManager(layoutManager)
        let newTextContainer = NSTextContainer(size: frame.size)
        layoutManager.addTextContainer(newTextContainer)
        super.init(frame: frame, textContainer: newTextContainer)
    }

    required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
        super.init(coder: aDecoder)
    }
}


does it mean I need to manually implement the textList in my layoutManager, or is there a easy way I can get the default implementation of textList of paragraphStyle for UITextStyle
